# Getting the query box to stay open

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

My hosting company have recently upgraded to phpmyadmin 4.4.10. In earlier versions when you ran a query and then clicked "Edit" the query box would open in a separate browser window which was great as it allowed you to keep adjusting the query and viewing the output in the main window without loosing it.

Checking "Retain query box" does what it says on the tin but it's not great, it will disappear if you click to view the next 25 results (default per page) or if you click show more results per page.

You loose your query entirely if you accidentally click a link to open another table (usually I remember to right click open in new tab)

If anyone knows a way to restore the previous behavior please help.

Using mysql client software on my local machine is an option but not an ideal one as my ip address changes frequently and I have to login to the control panel and add it to a mysql remote connection whitelist

Comment: As a sidenote... Have a look at dyn.com services. I used them on dynamic ip and their url replaced the changing up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For normal query adjusting, click on "Edit inline" if the query is still visible.
If you accidently lose your query, it's still available in the Console (bottom link of the main panel) which contains an history of your queries, and you can edit them.

Comment: I just started getting used to the new console. I really preferred the separate query box window though :/

Comment: So annoying that there's no setting to permanently retain the query box!

Comment: phpadmin does what I need, but I don't know how to control it. It is luck for me when it happens.  Example:  just a few minutes ago, I was running a series of queries separated by ; all in one query window.  After running, all the queries were just as i had entered them, still in the open query window.  Ran the set 20+ times.  One wrong click, now, after running the same set of queries, the queries are distributed among multiple query windows. To re-run, I have to collect them all from various places and put them back in the window.  Where is the control for keeping the query window open?

Answer (score 0):

If you're really adamant about keeping the query window open, you can write a js scriptlet as a browser bookmark, let it search the DOM for an object with the class name "inline_edit_sql" and click on on page (full) load.

Comment: what is  this "browser favorite" ?

Comment: I meant to say 'bookmark;' Chrome, and I'm sure other modern browsers, allow the placement of Javascript in place of the url of a bookmark.